# Why does ggplot (.predict) not change color/palette in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, rms

Please find `My Data` below. I have the following plot

[image]

I want to apply the "jco"-palette (or just manually typing a "#xxxxxx"-color). However, I cant make it work. I have tried

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsci)
ggplot(Predict(model, ref.zero = TRUE, fun=exp)) + scale_color_jco() + scale_fill_jco()
```

How can I

1) Manually change the color to #xxxxxx?

2) Apply the JCO-palette?

```
My Data

library(rms)
model <- cph(Surv(Follow.up.death,Death)~rcs(total.mbq),data=w)

w <- structure(list(Follow.up.death = c(18, 2, 14, 17, 31, 4, 20, 
15, 12, 19, 10, 17, 27, 22, 3, 43, 24, 14, 13, 5, 12, 137, 22, 
87, 48, 24, 72, 32, 14, 83, 68, 56, 57, 18, 16, 70, 1.9, 69.2, 
126.3, 41.6, 17.9, 1.3, 87.4, 4.4, 137.4, 17.5, 95.8, 65.2, 14.8, 
98.5, 16.6, 74.9, 10.3, 43.4, 32.5, 4.8, 7.3, 107.8, 6.8, 18.3, 
33, 25.2, 49.2, 15.9, 1.2, 42.7, 1, 9, 1.8, 15.6, 8.9, 15, 16.4, 
7.7, 75.5, 12.2, 54.8, 22.2, 9.7, 14.3, 5.2, 64.5, 21.8, 0.2, 
7.3, 18.7, 5.1, 17.3, 27.4, 16, 24.2, 9.7, 8.2, 5.7, 41.8, 10.6, 
22.8, 4.8, 6, 4, 50, 21, 30, 5, 11, 12), Death = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), total.mbq = c(29354L, 7445L, 22309L, 
29699L, 29711L, 14765L, 22257L, 29715L, 29772L, 13320L, 20905L, 
12950L, 3400L, 14800L, 7400L, 21890L, 19400L, 14800L, 14700L, 
22200L, 1688L, 4500L, 8438L, 13500L, 14800L, 12580L, 12950L, 
13320L, 11840L, 13320L, 14800L, 13690L, 11250L, 12210L, 13320L, 
13320L, 14800L, 12580L, 20720L, 11840L, 14800L, 7030L, 14800L, 
14800L, 8325L, 11100L, 10730L, 13690L, 12210L, 14800L, 13320L, 
14800L, 12950L, 22200L, 17945L, 22200L, 8140L, 13690L, 11581L, 
14430L, 13320L, 13320L, 21090L, 11100L, 3885L, 6475L, 6660L, 
6660L, 5920L, 7500L, 5000L, 12500L, 12500L, 10000L, 12500L, 7500L, 
15000L, 10000L, 5000L, 7500L, 5000L, 15000L, 12500L, 7500L, 7500L, 
7500L, 5000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 12500L, 5000L, 5000L, 10000L, 
12500L, 5000L, 10000L, 10000L, 22200L, 14800L, 29000L, 14000L, 
4800L, 21600L, 28800L, 11400L)), .Names = c("Follow.up.death", 
"Death", "total.mbq"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-106L))
```

Comment: You haven't assigned anything to the color aesthetic—something needs to be in `aes(color = ...)`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried ggplot(Predict(model, ref.zero = TRUE, fun=exp), aes(color="red")), but this gives an error: `Error in facets[[2]] : subscript out of bounds`. Can you produce an example of how you would type it?

Comment: So that sounds like you have facets set that aren't included in your code here. It's also unclear what you're trying to color, or what the color and scales would be acting on. I'd recommend taking a step back to go through some `ggplot2` tutorials more broadly; [this](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html) is a good one